# Why parent process has to close all file descriptors of a pipe before calling wait( )?

Tags: c, process, pipe, parent-child

I do not know why the parent process needs to close both the file descriptors of a pipe before calling `wait()`?

I have a C program which does:

1. Parent creates child_a, which executes `ls -l` using execvp, and writes to the pipe (after closing read end of pipe).
2. Parent creates another child (without closing any file descriptor for pipe), called child_b, which executes 'wc' by reading from pipe.(after closing write end of pipe).
3. Parent waits for both children to complete by calling `wait()` twice.

I noticed that program is blocked if parent does not close both file descriptors of the pipe before calling the `wait()` syscall. Also after reading few questions already posted online it looks like this is the general rule and needs to be done. But I could not find the reason why this has to be done?

Why does `wait()` not return if the parent does not close the file descriptors of the pipe?

I was thinking that, in the worst case, if the parent does not close the file descriptor of pipe, then the only consequence would be that the pipe would keep existing (which is a waste of resource). But I never thought this would block the execution of child process (as can be seen because `wait()` does not return).

Also remember, parent is not using the pipe at all. It is `child_a` writing in the pipe, and `child_b` reading from the pipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the parent process doesn't close the write ends of the pipes, the child processes never get EOF (zero bytes read) because there's a process that might (but won't) write to the pipe.  The child process must also close the write end of the pipe for the same reason — if it doesn't, there's a process (itself) that might (but won't) write to the pipe, so the read won't return EOF.

If you duplicate one end of a pipe to standard output or standard error, you should close both ends of that pipe.  It is a common mistake not to have enough calls to `close()` in multiprocess code using pipes.  Occasionally, you get away with being sloppy, but the details vary by case and usually you don't.

Comment: Thanks for the parent part. Few questions on child part though. I did not close the write end in `child_a` but the program still works (child_b reads from the pipe and i can see the output of child_b in monitor). How come ? Was it because `child_a` called `execvp( )`?

Comment: Child A executes `ls`; that generates data on standard output without reading from standard input.  When it is done generating the data, it finishes, and the pipe descriptors are closed as it finishes.  However, in your scenario, Child B (aka `wc`) is reading from its standard input.  The parent process still has the write end of the pipe that is Child B's standard input open, so `wc` never gets EOF and never terminates.  There's also a chance that Child B has the write end of the pipe open too; that would also mean that `wc` never gets EOF.